# In CefSharp, how to disable proxy while the program is running

Tags: proxy, cefsharp

Now, I already know how to modify the network proxy. But i want to disable it, not modify it.

```
Cef.UIThreadTaskFactory.StartNew(delegate {
      var rc = chromeBrowser.GetBrowser().GetHost().RequestContext;
      var v = new Dictionary<string, object>();
      v["mode"] = "fixed_servers";
      v["server"] = "scheme://server:port;
      string error;
      bool success = rc.SetPreference("proxy", v, out error);                
    });
```

I want to implement it like

```
var cefSettings = new CefSharp.CefSettings();
cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("no-proxy-server","1");
```

**but, I want to disable proxy at runtime**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You must not use CefCommandLineArgs that setting proxy. You must set proxy how you written above.You must set proxy behind Cef.Initialize() how you written above.

2)Replace mode to "DIRECT" - it disabled connection with proxy.

```
v["mode"] = "direct";
```

3) You can check actual connection information if you will loading page "chrome://net-internals#proxy"

Comment: Yes, I tested that I can really disable connection with proxy. thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, because the english is not good, I am not familiar with this website. I forgot to accept the answer before, and I apologize to you.I am sorry